# Kotlin top level function not visible when used from other Maven project

Tags: maven, kotlin

The following code works from within the same project:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

val Any.log: Logger
    get() = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)
```

Example usage:

```
log.info("hi!")
```

When I try it from another project I get a compilation error:

```
Cannot access 'log': it is internal in 'com.mycompany'
```

Why is this happening and how can I make it work?

Answer (score -1):

I don't get it entirely but I've figured it out. It does work like this:

```
class Logger {
    companion object {
        val log: Logger
            get() = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)
    }
}
```